# Why doesn't the istringstream eof flag become true when successfully converting a boolean string value to a bool?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am learning how to convert values stored as a string to native types using `istringstream`. When a number stored as a string is successfully converted to an `int` or `double`, the istringstream eof() function returns true. When a boolean stored as a string is successfully converted to a `bool`, eof() returns false.

What causes the difference and why does eof() not return true when there seems to be no other characters remaining to process?

Code for converting to a bool:

```
string value = "true";
istringstream converter(value);
bool convertedValue;

if (!(converter >> std::boolalpha >> convertedValue)){
    cout << "Conversion error." << endl;
} else {
    cout << "Conversion success." << endl;
}

cout << "convertedValue=" << convertedValue << "  value.length()=" << value.length() << "  converter.tellg()=" << converter.tellg() << "  converter.eof()=" << converter.eof() << endl;
```

The output shows the eof flag is false:

```
Conversion success.
convertedValue=1  value.length()=4  converter.tellg()=4  converter.eof()=0
```

Code for converting to a double:

```
string value = "1234.56";
istringstream converter(value);
double convertedValue;

if (!(converter >> std::boolalpha >> convertedValue)){
    cout << "Conversion error." << endl;
} else {
    cout << "Conversion success." << endl;
}

cout << "convertedValue=" << convertedValue << "  value.length()=" << value.length() << "  converter.tellg()=" << converter.tellg() << "  converter.eof()=" << converter.eof() << endl;
```

The output shows the eof flag is true:

```
Conversion success.
convertedValue=1234.56  value.length()=7  converter.tellg()=-1  converter.eof()=1
```

Code for converting to an int:

```
string value = "1234";
istringstream converter(value);
int convertedValue;

if (!(converter >> std::boolalpha >> convertedValue)){
    cout << "Conversion error." << endl;
} else {
    cout << "Conversion success." << endl;
}

cout << "convertedValue=" << convertedValue << "  value.length()=" << value.length() << "  converter.tellg()=" << converter.tellg() << "  converter.eof()=" << converter.eof() << endl;
```

The output shows the eof flag is true:

```
Conversion success.
convertedValue=1234  value.length()=4  converter.tellg()=-1  converter.eof()=1
```

I am using g++ (Debian 4.8.3-3) 4.8.3.

Comment: Why do you want to check eof in istringstream ?!

Comment: I was trying to figure out a surefire way to test if the conversion used the entire value, or ignored part of it (like reading a double into an int), for a successful conversion. To check this I am currently using `if (!converter.eof() && (converter.tellg() != value.length()))` because eof does not reutrn true for bool types, and I'm really curious why.

Comment: @user3371448 See my answer. It is more detailed.

Comment: Learn from the best, take a look at Boost's `lexical_cast()` function. You will find that they extract an additional `std::ws`, which will skip whitespace, and check for EOF then.

Comment: Because tellg() returns a pos_type and length() returns a size_type, what's the safest way to cast or perform the comparison? I just noticed I get a "Type comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions" warning on compile.

Comment: To answer my own question, to eliminate compiler warnings, I used `static_cast()`: 
`if (!converter.eof() && (static_cast<string::size_type>(converter.tellg()) != value.length()))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The state of "End of File" is reached after the first unsuccessful input operation, where there is nothing more to input.

In the case of reading from a string, an input operation reads one character.

Inputting a boolean ("true") does not have to try and read a character beyond the 'e'. This is in contrast to input operations for numbers, where there may be a next digit.

To determine, whether all has been read: check whether the tellg result is -1 or equal to the string length.

Comment: This makes sense. I didn't see the pattern where eof=1 when tellg()=-1. Should this always be the case?

Comment: Before reading the first, tellg ought to return 0. Before the last, it should be length-1, and length after the last read. So, after one unsuccessful read, it goes to -1, and the result of tellg can't be used in a seekg, because the eofbit flag is set.

Answer (score 1):

According to the C++ Standard

> Successive characters in the range [in,end) (see 23.2.3) are obtained
>   and matched against corresponding positions in the target sequences
>   only as necessary to identify a unique match.

So for example if to compile the following code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

int main() 
{
    std::istringstream is( "trueabc" );
    bool b = false;

    is >> std::boolalpha >> b;

    std::cout << std::boolalpha << b << std::endl;

    std::cout << is.eof() << std::endl;

    std::string s;

    is >> s;

    std::cout << s << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

using GCC (at www.ideone.com) or MS VC++ 2010 then the result will be the same

```
true
false
abc
```

That is it was enough to read "true" from the input stream that to determine the "**unique match**".

It is interesting to note that it seems that MS VC++ 2010 contains a bug. If to compile the following code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>

int main() 
{
    std::istringstream is( "true" );
    bool b = false;

    is >> std::boolalpha >> b;

    std::cout << std::boolalpha << b << std::endl;

    std::cout << is.eof() << std::endl;


    return 0;
}
```

then the output will be

**MS VC++ 2010:**

```
true
true
```

**GCC:**

```
true
false
```